# how do you call restful api in angular2 server

Tags: web-services, https, server, frontend, angular2-services

I was asked "how do you call restful api in angular2 server" in a front end interview before. I said using the http. But interviewer didn't seem satisfied with this answer. What is the correct answer? Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

I was asked the same question in almost every interview I had, such as

- How do you consume Restful web services in Angular 2/4
- How do you create RESTful Webservice? and couple other such as
- REST vs SOAP, etc.

---

Since I worked on Angular 2/4 and RESTful web services, I know the story about how they work. So rather than just answering "using Http protocol" I would elaborate on the answer by mentioning

- The HttpClient in @angular/common/http offers a simplified client HTTP API for Angular applications
- How you call the CRUD operations from service.ts file,  use of observables and subscribe() method in component.ts file. (the component subscribes to the method's return value)
  https://angular.io/guide/http .     - *more info*
- The 5 types of Http methods or for CRUD operations we use like 
  HTTP GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH and their functionality, 
  https://restfulapi.net/http-methods/
- The way we use Postman collections (in my case) to test REST API calls or Swagger, etc. The format the data gets processed ( in this case of REST its JSON ). (JSON importance if necessary)

Please comment if you find any other reference or better points to answer coz I am learning too.